# OkHttp response different

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using Okhttp3 to get Json data. I post two parameters which in response should give me Json data.The onResponse method is called but I get the response as "okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@21e14bf0" instead of Json. This is the first time I am using Okhttp. Please look through the below code:

Code:

```
String url="http://xxxxx.com/data.php";
OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody requestbody=new FormBody.Builder().add("name",usr_nme).add("date",date).build();
Request request=new Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestbody).build();
okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        } else {
            // do something wih the result
            Log.e("Response",response.body().toString());

            progressDialog.cancel();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Exception(Edited):

:

```
  {"user_details":{"numeron_user":[{"nme_nmbr":1,"details":"The 1 is a doer, a powerful force"},{"lfepth_nmbr":8,"details":"You are strong tough and can be ruthless. You enjoy continuous hassles and struggle for power."},{"day_nmbr":4,"details":"Number 4 resonates with the vibrations and energies of practicality, organization and exactitude"},{"more_info":"If birth or lifepath number is 4 or 8 the name number should be in the vibration of 1,3,5,6. Change your name so that it produces the vibration of the previously said numbers.  Never increase the vibration of 4 or 8 in your life.\r\n\r\nFor selecting a mobile phone number make sure the number adds up to 1,3,5 or 6."}]}}
10-24 15:30:16.681 6974-7502/com.root5solutions.numerology E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                                             Process: com.root5solutions.numerology, PID: 6974
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
                                                                                 at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:398)
                                                                                 at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:392)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:449)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
                                                                                 at com.root5solutions.numerology.UserInput$BackgroundTask$1.onResponse(UserInput.java:118)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-24 15:30:16.791 6974-6974/com.root5solutions.numerology E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `response.body().toString()` to `response.body().string()`.

Comment: What is the difference b/w toString and just string

Comment: I changed it.Now I am getting "okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@3c62aeab" as response

Comment: `ResponseBody` doesn't implement `toString`, which is why you're getting the default `Object.toString` output. Instead it defines its own method `string` that produces the response data. It confused me too at first.

Comment: DId you change both instances, because you use it twice in your code.

Comment: Still getting the response similar to the first to the first one.

Comment: Will try it now

Comment: App crashed now,but Json has been displayed. Will edit the question now.

Comment: Please look into the edited question.Is there a problem with Json structure as I cannot parse it.

Comment: Only call `string` once. Call it, save its value to a variable, then use the variable from that point onwards.

Comment: Exceptoin vanished now.Why doesn't it work when we try to parse "response.body.string". We are parsing it in the same onResponse method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157360/discussion-between-leo-aso-and-jobin).